# Physics.SE color layout change

Tags: feature-request, design

Most of the questions here are about the content, and not about the layout of the site. (Which is good, content >> layout, in terms of importance).

I'm new in SE, as you can probably see, however, I have a few recommendations, hopefully they're not frowned upon.

As it is, when one clicks on a topic in physics.SE, the title (in the main site) changes color. That happens so one can see if we clicked on a topic already or not. However, that change in color is almost unnoticeable. Is it me only?

So, the question is:

- Is it possible to change the color of clicked topics (`a:visited`)? Would you want to have it changed, as well?

Comment: I probably should edit the question, but for now I'll comment. If you check askubuntu.com, you'll see that their color system is much easier on the eyes.

Comment: As one who is colorblind, I can tell you I struggle with the slight differences in color on most of the things here...

Comment: @tpg2114 Would it be too hard to have it changed? I mean, can the mods of physics.SE do it, or does it need to be discussed with SE?

Comment: Related: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/2955/2451

Comment: The mods can't change such things, but there is a employee (or more than one, now) of Stack Exchange who does the design. That said, changes are rare and incremental once a design is selected.

Comment: @dmckee, that's bad news. It probably won't happen then...(?)

Comment: You never know until you try.

Comment: @Crake If you stay here for long enough, you will quickly learn how resilient the people in charge of SE is to changes, They have found a formula that works and they will rather accept having several teeth removed without anesthetics than doing any change. Welcome on board, Sir.

Comment: @Crake Not necessarily, the accept tick color was changed to accomadate for the colorblind and others with poor eyesight. In the past the difference between the tick and the greyed out tick next to answers on one's own question was very faint. Not anymore. Such small color changes are made pretty easily if there's support for it.

Comment: In the meantime, you may want to use the Stylish extension (for Chrome or Firefox), and change the color assigned to `a:visited` for Physics.SE

Comment: @Manishearth, How would one know if there's support for it? This post has 2 upvotes only, and no answers, I guess there's not enough people worried about that

Comment: @Crake It's still early. I don't know how Jin judges if a design change has support, though.

Comment: @Crake What do you think about the same links color in other sites, compared with here? Can you justify it a bit? The previous tick problem is a bigger problem because it is indistinguishable in poor monitor, not only weak eyesightn

Comment: @hwlau, if you go to Askubuntu.com, you can clearly see which topics you clicked and which you didn't. The same happens in stackoverflow. Also, according to my ophthalmologist, I have perfect vision.

Comment: Also, instead of changing the color, one could always make it italic, or bold, I don't know. It's something that would need to be tested, I think.

Comment: So ya, I guess nothing gets done here.