# Text color of topics on Physics.SE frontpage

Tags: feature-request, design

On *Physics'* [starting page](https://physics.stackexchange.com), the color used for the topic texts is quite pale blue, [#0587AC](https://www.color-hex.com/color/0587AC) to a color picker.

Most pixels are even brighter than that because they are anti-aliased against the white background.

Such low-contrast texts might build barriers, reduce legibility and reading them is more fatiguing to the eye than necessary.

As an alternative, https://math.stackexchange.com is using a much darker color of [#0F3559](https://www.color-hex.com/color/0F3559) which is much more comfortable.

The current color scheme on PSE is such that already followed links get darker, which is easier to read.
Maybe something could be improved about this? Once there was a request due to hard
noticeable color difference between fresh links and followed ones in [Physics.SE color layout change](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5051/251841), which is also a point to consider, but less important IMHO than legibility in the first place.

Comment: Perhaps raise this issue in the context of [the current network-wide evaluation of accessible color schemes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/386102/280545)?